# Botocore error: HTTP Client raised an unhandled exception: sys.meta_path must be a list of import hooks

Tags: python, pandas, amazon-s3, parquet, pyarrow

I am running this small snippet to upload a panda dataframe to s3 using parquet. But I get the error:

`Exception botocore.exceptions.HTTPClientError: HTTPClientError(u'An HTTP Client raised an  unhandled exception: sys.meta_path must be a list of import hooks',) in <bound method S3File.__del__ of <S3File /my-bucket-name/parquet/six>> ignored`

The code seems to work sometimes from the python shell.  And on the python shell it does not print any error.

But when running with
python ./the_script.py

It prints that error

```
from pyarrow import Table
import pyarrow.parquet as pq
import numpy as np
from s3fs import S3File, S3FileSystem
import pandas as pd

fs = S3FileSystem()
bucket_uri = 's3://my-bucket-name/parquet/six'

df = pd.DataFrame({'one': [-1, np.nan, 2.5],
               'two': ['foo', 'bar', 'baz'],
               'three': [True, False, True]},
               index=list('abc'))
               
table = Table.from_pandas(df.copy())
s3file = S3File(fs, bucket_uri, mode='wb')
pq.write_table(table, s3file)
```

parts of the snippet are copy pasted from:
https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/parquet.html?highlight=pyarrow%20parquet%20partition

Python = 2.7.12

botocore = 1.14.9

s3fs = 0.4.2

pandas = 0.24.2

pyarrow = 1.0.0

Ubuntu 16.04

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Was using the wrong ( or probably low level ) function

Instead of
pq.write_table(table, s3file)
Do
pq.write_to_dataset(table=table, root_path=bucket_uri, filesystem=fs )

https://www.jitsejan.com/interacting-with-parquet-on-s3.html